# google cloud kubernetes ingress not redirecting to https

Tags: django, docker, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

i deployed a django application in google cloud kubernetes, its all working i can access my site from https and use it. but when i type in the url the domain it opens with http, if i write https i can access too, i searched a lot and tried a lot of stuff in the internet still no success.
there is a annotation

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.allowHTTP: "false" # <-- this one
```

this works disableing the http access, but i want to redirect to https not blocking, if i write in the browser url my domain it goes to http first.
its all working the ssl and nginx ingress, i just can't redirect the access from http to https.

here is my nginx ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: django-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: django-ip
    spec.ingressClassName: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true" # <--- this one is not working
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-forwarded-headers: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - example-django.com
      secretName: django-certs
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: django-svc
      port: 
        name: django-core-http
  rules:
    - host: example-django.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: django-svc
                port:
                  name: django-core-http
```

tried annotations

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.allowHTTP: "false"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
```

installed nginx ingress with this
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke

Comment: Gateway configuration sets up a proxy to act as a load balancer exposing port 80 and 9080 (http), 443 (https), 9443(https) and port 2379 (TCP) for ingress. Check whether the port 443 is exposed or not. Create the internal HTTPS Load balancer and redirect the traffic to the Load balancer.

Comment: The HTTP load balancer has a shared IP address that redirects traffic from port 80 to port 443. Refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/setting-up-http-to-https-redirect#creating_the_internal_https_load_balancer) for more information on [http to https redirect.](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#https_redirect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After try and error, i just moved from google cloud kubernetes to digital ocean and im loving it. It's all working properly

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a certificate and key for your service, create a Kubernetes secret for the ingress gateway.Under servers: There should already be a section under servers: for port 80 HTTP.
To redirect HTTP to HTTPS, add the value httpsRedirect: true under tls in the HTTP server section.

Comment: i did some research, so basically i need to install istio in the gck and deploy a yaml file of kind: Gateway with httpsRedirect: true?
i am using the ManagedCertificate for the ssl